# Generators of $H^1 (T)$: take two

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

[Previously](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1087185/39599), I asked about how to prove that $dx + dy$ is a generator of the de Rham cohomology group of the torus.

Now it occurred to me that $dx$ and $dy$ are both also generators of $H^1(T)$. Please can you tell me if this is correct?

(1) To find a complete set of generators of $H^1(T)$ I have to find two differential $1$-forms that are closed but not exact and that do not differ by an exact $1$-form.

(2) Since $dx,dy$ is a pair of closed $1$-forms that are not exact they are promising candidates.

(3) Now I only need to prove that $dx , dy$ do not differ by an exact $1$-form.

> How can I prove that $dx$ and $dy$ do not differ by an exact one form?

Comment: The de Rham cohomology class of the one-form $dx + dy$ is not a generator of $H^1(T)$ as $H^1(T)$ is two dimensional. What you've said about $dx$ and $dy$ is correct, but requires justification.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese No what I meant is that $dx + dy$ is one out of two generators.

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to a part of John's answer to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1087185/39599), so I will leave you to fill in the details.

Suppose $dx$ and $dy$ differed by an exact form. Then $dx - dy = df$ for some $f \in C^{\infty}(T)$. Now let $\gamma$ be a closed loop and consider $\int_{\gamma}dx - dy$; you should be able to conclude that this must be zero. Now find a particular loop $\gamma$ for which the integral isn't zero.

Comment: Can I think of $x,y$ as angles $x,y \in [0,2\pi]$ parameterising $S^1 \times S^1$?

Comment: Are the generators of the first cohomology the total derivatives of these angle functions?

Comment: I think these questions have become part of your [new question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1091382/39599). I have given an answer there; hopefully it goes some way to clarifying any confusion you're having.