# $H^1_{dR}(S^1 \times S^1) = H^1_{dR}(S^1) \oplus H^1_{dR}(S^1)$ without Künneth?

Tags: homology-cohomology, differential-forms

As in the title: I am trying to derive $H^1_{dR}(S^1 \times S^1) = H^1_{dR}(S^1) \oplus H^1_{dR}(S^1)$.

First let me share my thoughts:

I am trying to derive that

$$ H^1_{dR}(S^1 \times S^1) = \mathbb R \oplus \mathbb R$$

I can do it by applying the Künneth theorem:

$$ H^n_{dR}(S^1 \times S^1) = \bigoplus_{i + j = n} H^i_{dR}(S^1) \otimes H^j_{dR}(S^1)$$

For the right hand side I get

$$ H^0(S^1)\otimes H^1(S^1) \bigoplus H^1(S^1)\otimes H^0(S^1) $$

And since $ H^1(S^1) = H^0(S^1) = \mathbb R$, this is equal to

$$ \mathbb R \otimes \mathbb R \bigoplus \mathbb R \otimes \mathbb R = \mathbb R \oplus \mathbb R$$

But this is an overkill.

> How to directly derive it?

Comment: What do you mean by "directly"?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I'm still trying to understand your answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1091426/180995). It is not clear to me why the product manifold $ M \times N$ is generated by the generators of $M$ and $N$ respectively. (By directly I mean without using heavy machinery, that is, by using geometric observations or perhaps basic theorems.)

Comment: I'm a little bit confused because you claimed to have already calculated $H^1_{\text{dR}}(S^1\times S^1)$ in the first line of the question that you linked to. The fact that the cohomology of $M\times N$ is generated by the generators of the cohomology of $M$ and $N$ separately is precisely what the Künneth Theorem tells you. If you would like to understand why this is true, you should read the proof. If for some reason you do not want to use the Künneth Theorem, I have provided two possible approaches to calculate $H^1_{\text{dR}}(S^1\times S^1)$ in my answer below.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I'm very sorry for the confusion. I calculated the cohomology by calculating the cellular homology and then using Poincare duality. But doing it like this left me with no clue about how to find generators of the cohomology...

Answer (score 3):

You can define two $1$-forms which give you a basis of the cohomology, and show by hand that every other $1$-form is cohomologous to a linear combination of them. This is not hard to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways of seeing that $H^1_{dR}(S^1\times S^1)$ is two-dimensional without using the Künneth Theorem.

1. For any smooth connected manifold $X$, $H^1_{dR}(X) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(X), \mathbb{R})$ (see Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (second edition) Theorem $17.17$ and Problem $18$-$2$),
   so

$$H^1_{\text{dR}}(S^1\times S^1) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(S^1\times S^1), \mathbb{R}) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^2, \mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^2.$$

2. For any smooth manifold $X$, we define the Euler characteristic of $X$ by $\chi(X) := \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\dim H^k_{\text{dR}}(X)$; for a two-dimensional manifold, this is just the usual Euler characteristic for surfaces.

   The two-dimensional manifold $S^1\times S^1$ is the torus which has Euler characteristic zero. As $S^1\times S^1$ is connected, $H^0_{\text{dR}}(S^1\times S^1) \cong \mathbb{R}$, and as $S^1\times S^1$ is a compact orientable two-dimensional manifold, $H^2_{\text{dR}}(S^1\times S^1) \cong \mathbb{R}$. Therefore,

   \begin{align*}
   \chi(S^1\times S^1) &= \dim H^0_{\text{dR}}(S^1\times S^1) - \dim H^1_{\text{dR}}(S^1\times S^1) + \dim H^2_{\text{dR}}(S^1\times S^1)\\
   0 &= 1 - \dim H^1_{\text{dR}}(S^1\times S^1) + 1,
   \end{align*}

   so $\dim H^1_{\text{dR}}(S^1\times S^1) = 2$.